# What is this simple javascript doing

Tags: javascript

I am reading a tutorial and keep getting stuck on the first line of code, I know "new" in php is to make an object, but this tutorial has nothing to do with that. please help

```
  var img = new Image();
```

the tutorial is here:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

Ok, I found the W3 definition of the predefined javascript object Image(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Comment: Just a little note, this particular line has no relation to jQuery whatsoever.

Comment: @BoltClock the tutorial is writen in jQuery!! `$(new Image()).attr("src", "image.png")`

Comment: I said "this particular line", not "the tutorial".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in JavaScript `new` is used when making objects too, just like PHP.

As you can guess, therefore, that line of code simply instantiates an [`Image`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/image.shtml) object and assigns it to the `img` variable.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thoight, however, the tutorial does not define the "Image" object

Comment: @A_funs: `Image` is a built-in DOM class that represents HTML images, so it's available to you by default in most if not all browsers.

Comment: If you use Firefox, and have Firebug installed, you can, after the page loads, enter something like console.log(img) or console.log(Image) to inspect things.  This would have told you that img is an instantiated instance of Image, and that Image is a function.  Then you would have know that Image is a built-in function, since you didn't define it yourself.

Comment: Ok, and that predefined "Image" function just creates a html <image> element?

Answer (score 0):

you can preload an image with

```
  var img = new Image();
```

they preload the image images/headshot.jpg

then they wait until it has been loaded

then thay hide the loading image and fade in the image

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Image is a native JavaScript object which corresponds to a HTML image object.

what the line means, is
"create a new variable 'img' and set it to a newly initialised Image object"

Comment: but in the tutorial the Image object isn't defined

Comment: the image object is created. it doesn't initially have any data associated with it. note that the tutorial first attaches an "onload" event to the image object, and /then/ sets a "src" attribute.

this has the effect of creating the object, loading the image, then running the onload event.

if you loaded the src /before/ setting the onload, then cached images would never fire their onload events

Comment: in the tutorial jQuery is used!!

Comment: yes. but Image is native JavaScript. and the sample code you supplied in the post has no jQuery in it

Answer (score 0):

It's make an  html form for you.

for detail read this http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/image.html

Hope this might help you a lot.

or you want to know it create

```js
var img = new Image();
```

and not use?

```js
$(img)
  // once the image has loaded, execute this code
  .load(function () {
    // set the image hidden by default    
    $(this).hide();

    // with the holding div #loader, apply:
    $('#loader')

    // remove the loading class (so no background spinner), 
    .removeClass('loading')
    // then insert our image
    .append(this);

    // fade our image in to create a nice effect
    $(this).fadeIn();
  })

    // if there was an error loading the image, react accordingly
   .error(function () {
   // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
   })

// *finally*, set the src attribute of the new image to our image
.attr('src', 'images/headshot.jpg');
});
```

The 'this' keyword is represent for img variable